# How to fix error <Configuration xmlns=''> was not expected when Deserialize xml

Tags: xml, serialization

I have config xml:

```
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>Gift Perfect</Name>
  <Designs>

  </Designs>
  <Root>

  </Root>
  <FormElements>

  </FormElements>   
</Configuration>
```

ConfigurationModel:

```
[Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot("Configuration", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", IsNullable = true)]
    public class ConfigurationModel
    {
        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Designs")]
        public string Designs { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Root")]
        public string Root { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to Deserialize it by this code:

```
var type = typeof(ConfigurationModel);
var s = new XmlSerializer(type);
var xml = string.Empty;

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/xml/Config.xml")))
{
    xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
}

TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
ConfigurationModel o = (ConfigurationModel)s.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();

var result = o;
```

I get the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: <Configuration xmlns=''> was not expected.
```

at line:

```
ConfigurationModel o = (ConfigurationModel)s.Deserialize(reader);
```

Plase help me find solution in this case.